# Scrolling overflowing elements into view along the x axis

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a bar with information about a game.

This bar has a maximum width.

There are buttons that are overflowing in a child div.

I want to be able to scroll these elements into view with Javascript. For example, when the button is pressed, I want the last button "Bring Me Into View" to scroll into view along the overflowing X direction, and then the main button "Overview" to scroll to the left into overflow space. However, I'm going wrong somewhere in my approach.

I'm using jQuery to try and simplify things, and can AI convert a jquery solution into vanilla JS.

```js
function scrollOverflowingElementsIntoView() {
    console.log("scrolling");
  $('.j-search-sug-items-view').animate({
    scrollLeft: '+='+100
  }, 500, 'swing');
}
```

```css
.jpr-top-bar {
  width: 1000px;
}
.j-search-suggestions {
  background: none;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.j-search-suggestions {
  color: var(--j-foreground);
  background: var(--j-background);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--j-border);
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.j-search-sug, .j-search-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: normal;
}

.j-search-sug {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.j-search-sug, .j-search-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: normal;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb {
  min-width: 92px;
  min-height: 92px;
}
.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb {
  min-width: 46px;
}
.j-search-sug-thumb {
  max-width: 32%;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb img {
  min-width: 92px;
  min-height: 92px;
}
.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.j-search-sug-thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-headings {
  padding: 0 0 0 11.09px;
  max-width: 239px;
}
.j-search-sug-headings {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.j-search-sug-title-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.j-search-sug-title-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-heading {
  font-size: 29.034px;
  line-height: 1.0;
}
.j-search-sug-heading {
  color: var(--j-foregroundEmphasis);
}
.j-search-sug-heading, .j-search-sug-subheading {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.j-search-sug-items {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-items-view {
  height: 36px;
}
.j-search-sug-items-view {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.j-search-sug-scroller {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(38px + 130px);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-width: none;
  width: auto;
}
.j-search-sug-items ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-search-sug-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 6px 0 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-items a.j-search-sug-link {
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jpr-top-bar">
    <div class="">
        <div class="j-search-suggestions j-no-touch j-screen-wide j-wrap-wide">
            <section class="j-search-sug j-has-image j-has-subheading">
                <div class="j-search-sug-inner">
                    <header class="j-search-sug-header">
                        <div class="j-search-sug-thumb"><img alt="" src=""></div>
                        <div class="j-search-sug-headings"><a class="j-search-sug-title-link" href="">
                                <h2 class="j-search-sug-heading">Minecraft</h2>
                                <h3 class="j-search-sug-subheading">Video Game</h3>
                            </a></div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="j-search-sug-items">
                        <div class="j-search-sug-items-view j-overflow-gradient-parent">
                            <div class="j-search-sug-scroller">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Gameplay</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Buy</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Reviews</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Trailers</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Guides</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Tips &amp; strategies</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Cheats</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Sequels</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Mojang</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Bring Me Into View</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                                                                    <
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="scrollOverflowingElementsIntoView()">
Test
</button>
```

Comment: From running your snippet, it seems your code allows you to scroll to see the overflowing elements. I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Beyond 1000px, there are many overflowing elements that are invisible. Using Javascript, I want to bring those elements into view, and the first few elements "Overview, Gamplay, and Buy" would go out of view to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scroll()` or `scrollTo()` methods with smooth behaviour to scroll to the left of your elements on the Test button `click` event, Here is an example:

```js
function scrollOverflowingElementsIntoView() {
    console.log("scrolling");
    var element = document.querySelector('.j-search-sug-scroller');
    element.scroll({
        left: 200,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
```

```css
.jpr-top-bar {
  width: 1000px;
}
.j-search-suggestions {
  background: none;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.j-search-suggestions {
  color: var(--j-foreground);
  background: var(--j-background);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--j-border);
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.j-search-sug, .j-search-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: normal;
}

.j-search-sug {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.j-search-sug, .j-search-suggestions {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: normal;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb {
  min-width: 92px;
  min-height: 92px;
}
.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb {
  min-width: 46px;
}
.j-search-sug-thumb {
  max-width: 32%;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb img {
  min-width: 92px;
  min-height: 92px;
}
.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-thumb img {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.j-search-sug-thumb img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-headings {
  padding: 0 0 0 11.09px;
  max-width: 239px;
}
.j-search-sug-headings {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.j-search-sug-title-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.j-search-sug-title-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-heading {
  font-size: 29.034px;
  line-height: 1.0;
}
.j-search-sug-heading {
  color: var(--j-foregroundEmphasis);
}
.j-search-sug-heading, .j-search-sug-subheading {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.j-search-sug-items {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-items-view {
  height: 36px;
}
.j-search-sug-items-view {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.j-search-sug-scroller {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(38px + 130px);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-width: none;
  width: auto;
}
.j-search-sug-items ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.j-search-suggestions, .j-search-suggestions *, .j-search-suggestions ::before, .j-search-suggestions ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.j-search-sug-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 6px 0 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

.j-wrap-wide .j-search-sug-items a.j-search-sug-link {
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jpr-top-bar" id="element">
    <div class="">
        <div class="j-search-suggestions j-no-touch j-screen-wide j-wrap-wide">
            <section class="j-search-sug j-has-image j-has-subheading">
                <div class="j-search-sug-inner">
                    <header class="j-search-sug-header">
                        <div class="j-search-sug-thumb"><img alt="" src=""></div>
                        <div class="j-search-sug-headings"><a class="j-search-sug-title-link" href="">
                                <h2 class="j-search-sug-heading">Minecraft</h2>
                                <h3 class="j-search-sug-subheading">Video Game</h3>
                            </a></div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="j-search-sug-items">
                        <div class="j-search-sug-items-view j-overflow-gradient-parent">
                            <div class="j-search-sug-scroller">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overview</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Gameplay</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Buy</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Reviews</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Trailers</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Guides</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Tips &amp; strategies</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Cheats</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Sequels</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Mojang</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Overflow</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="j-search-sug-item"><a href="" class="j-search-sug-link"><span>Bring Me Into View</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                                                                    <
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="scrollOverflowingElementsIntoView()">
Test
</button>
```